# Multiple forms in one jsp

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp, multiple-forms

I have two form on one jsp page. The first form doesn't use the modelAttribute and the second one uses an modelAttribute. What the problem is, is that if I post the first form which I doesn't use the modelAttribute will claim an error that I haven't bind the modelAttribute.

I have searched on the internet to look for solutions but I can't find one which was helpfull.

changeAddress.jsp

```
<form method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="0" />
     <input type="submit" name="exist" value="send to this address" />
</form>
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="addressForm">
     <form:input path="street" />     
     <input type="submit" name="add" value="send to this address" />  
</form:form>
```

OrderController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="changeAddress",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showChangAddress(Model model)
{
     model.addAttribute("addressForm", new AddressForm());
     return new ModelAndView("body.changeaddress");
}

@RequestMapping(value="changeAddress", params="add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addChangAddress(@ModelAttribute("addressForm") @Valid AddressForm af, BindingResult result, Model model)
{
     System.out.println("a");
     return new ModelAndView("body.changeaddress");
}

@RequestMapping(value="changeAddress", params="exist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processChangAddress(@RequestParam(value="id") String id, Model model)
{
     System.out.println("b");
     return new ModelAndView("body.changeaddress");
}
```

Much appriciated for help :)

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: Can you try submitting only the first form using document.forms[0].submit.

Answer (score 3):

The spring form taglib [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-formtag)  about the `<form>` tag:

> This tag renders an HTML 'form' tag and exposes a binding path to inner tags for binding. It puts the command object in the PageContext so that the command object can be accessed by inner tags.

I think you don't need anything from the spring `<form>` tag in your first form. So you can use a simple html form instead:

```
<form method="post" action="...">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="0" />
     <input type="submit" name="exist" value="send to this address" />
<form>
```

Comment: I have done that but it puts me in the same situation with the same error